# Using embedded mongo in spring for local testing only

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, testing, embedded-database

I'm trying to use the flapdoodle embedded mongo database ('de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo')
for local manual testing the way I'd use H2 for relational database testing. I only want the embedded mongo to start up when running under the 'local' SPring profile, but I can't figure out how to make it happen -- it just always starts under any profile.

I've tried adding `@SpringBootApplication(exclude=EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)`  to my application (thinking I could reimport that autoconfig to a single profile later) but that doesn't seem to have any affect.

Anyone know how to limit it to a single profile, in a way that will work when running in Eclipse as well as via Gradle?

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two ways:

1- Load your dependency only in specific profile in maven or gradle

**Maven**

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
 </profiles>
```

**Gradle**

```
if (project.hasProperty('local')) {
    dependencies {
       compile 'de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:2.0.4-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
```

2- Using @Profile and @Import in your class

**LoadEmbeded.java**

```
@Profile(value = "local")
@Configuration
@Import(EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)
public class LoadEmbeded {

}
```

Hope it can give your a idea about it

---

**Edit 1:**
I have tested my approach and made a very simple application. It works with `@Profile`. Here is what I tested.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)
public class DemoApplication {

    @Autowired
    TestRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner() {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println(repository.save(new Test()));
            System.out.println(repository.findAll());
        };
    }
}

@Repository
interface TestRepository extends MongoRepository<Test, String> {

}

@Document
class Test {

    @Id
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Test setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this)
                .append("id", id)
                .toString();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Profile("local")
@Import(EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)
class Load {

}
```

And `application.properties`

```
spring.profiles.active=local
```

When I changed active profile to something else but **local**, it throws exception during startup and complaining about connection of mongodb. But when I set it **local**, it works and shows me the id of saved test entity.

If still you are experiencing same problem, maybe one of your dependencies is loading the Embedded MongoDB again even you exclude it. Usually it should be with test dependencies. Check your dependencies.

Comment: That's interesting, as I hadn't encountered that type of conditional dependency in Gradle before. I guess I should have been clearer that I was referring to Spring profiles, and am generally running from inside Eclipse. Sounds like this might work for someone just using `gradle bootRun` though.

Comment: Option 2 was part of what I was thinking, but I'd first need a way to exclude it from all the other profiles. My attempts to do that so far have failed.

Comment: I don't think it is related to the IDE that you use. I am using Intellij and still it detects my conditions in maven and gradle. I think it should work. For option two: check this `spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration` and also check your test files to not include autoconfigure again, if you use it in your test and don't exclude it from profiles, it will load the autoconfigure because it is in you classpath already. Also you might want to test `@Profile('!local')` for excluding it too

Comment: @BradMace I updated my answer with and working example